# Bootstrap Wysiwyg Editor: Saved Data in HTML to Database, trying to send the HTML back to the editor in richtextbox format

Tags: c#, html, twitter-bootstrap, wysiwyg

So, I have the rich text box editor from Bootstrap-Wysiwyg.

If the textbox contains: 
    **This is a bold statement.**

Then my DB will save the text as: 
(using a hidden tab where I insert the editor.html())

```
<b>This is a bold statement.<b>
```

If I save the file again, the RTF will convert it to:

```
&lt;b&gt;This is a bold statement.&lt;b&gt;
```

When I put the this text back into the editor using a Model.Value, it does not convert it to rich text but instead keeps the text as though it were a string and states it exactly as it is saved in the DB.

How can I convert the text in my model to show up in the rich text editors format?

I've been searching the net quite a bit, and most functionality refers to files. This is a new subject to me, so any insight is appreciated on how to fix this. (Editing text without formatting is obnoxious!) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Just in case someone else gets stuck, I was able to resolve this issue by doing the following:

I created a hidden div (which I populate first with my Model):

```
<textarea style="display: none;" id="editorCopy" name="body">@Model.Body</textarea>
```

and left my editor div empty:

```
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true">
    </div>
```

and in my JQuery:

I set my editors text to my hidden divs value, and on submit, I replace the hidden div with my editor text:

```
    $('#editor').html($('#editorCopy').val());

    $('#postSubmit').click(function () {
         $('#editorCopy').val($('#editor').html());
    });
```

This allowed my rich text to show on edit. There might be a better solution, but at least this works! :]